# Can CodeIgniter Table class generate table without cellspacing/cellpadding

Tags: codeigniter

As the title states, I'm looking for a way to generate a table with the table class, aka using `$this->table->generate($data)` without the cellspacing and cellpadding attributes, as these are no longer considered valid.

As stated by the w3c validator, "The cellpadding attribute on the table element is obsolete. Use CSS instead."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the template before generating the table.

```
$this->table->set_template(array(
    'table_open' => '<table>'
));
```

Then use CSS to style the tables as W3C says.

```
/* override cellspacing */
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

/* override cellpadding */
td, th {
    padding: 0;
}
```

If you need to apply it to only specific tables, use a CSS class and apply the class with the template config.